# How to solve ssl error 02001003?

Tags: ssl, cmd, npm

You can see this error in console under this text. How to solve ssl error 02001003 ? i'm trying to update npm but it's not working...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2dxS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.0e on https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

after install, go in this directory : C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin

open cmd (command line) and type this line  :

**Set OPENSSL=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg**

and finally type this :

**openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 9999 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout pri.pen -out pub.pen**

reply questions to generate certificates public and private

You can watch this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8GxM9ApkYc